# How to add an empty layer to my layerSwitcher in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

i am trying to add a couple of layers to my map, but these layers must be empty. I mean when i activate this layer it must return an alert or something similar saying "Coming soon".

```
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            }),
            /* new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Capas de información',
                layers: [ ]
            }) */

        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            zoom: true,
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }).extend([
            scaleLineControl
        ]),
        view: vista,
        interactions: new ol.interaction.defaults({
            altShiftDragRotate: false
        }),

    });

    const layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Leyenda'
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

This is my layerSwitcher where i want to add these layers:

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv5e6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty vector layer will show in a layer switcher and can also be used display attributions

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Empty layer',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    attributions: '© No data'
  })
})
```

Comment: But it only shows a text under the map, i mean something bigger maybe to cover the map or in the middle.

Comment: You could use a tile layer with a message in the tiles such as https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-tod7t?file=/main.js